# What is the relationship between schema and service_name in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, database-schema

When I connect to an oracle database(11g), I have to use the following information:
Schema name(username), password, Service_name(database name?).

The connection string looks like 'schemaName/pwd@host:1521/serviceName'.

I understand that the Schema is almost same as User. The schema which contains a collection of all objects like tables, indexs, views, etc is owned by a user.
My question is if the schema already contains tables and other objects, why do we have to specify the service_name when trying to connect.(In a client tool or config in tns file)
Because using schema_name/password, we can locate the individual tables which we want, what is the role of service_name here?

Comment: A schema name on its own is not sufficient to connect - you need to specify what database instance you wish to connect to; service name is a good way of specifying the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is one of the ways the connection can differ between different databases on the same machine/server/computer. In theory, you could not mention this and still get on the correct database (if there is only 1 database), but in context of database connection, all parameters need to be explicitally given. I believe this is because of both security and because of double-checking.

Notice the port number is given as well, that is another way of differing between database. But, know that different databases can be accessed via the same port.

The service is often the hint towards the actual database instance one is connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Service name identifies the service (database) you want to connect to. On top of that, there are additional features that depend on the service you use for connecting: for example resource manager, tracing, collection of performance statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Services are things that keep running in the background of the OS. So every database you use is a service which keeps running. Say for eg. If you have two database softwares installed say oracle and mysql, you need to specify which service to connect to. I hope this answers your question on `service_name`.

Comment: I think the service you meant is not the same as the service in the question. It's called 'service_name' only because it's configured in oracle configuration file. e.g. in 'tnsnames.ora' file:   My_Oracle =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostAddress)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = appdev)
    )
  )

Comment: Ha, actually you're right. I didn't realize that it has its reason to be named service before. It's running under the OS with different service name to differentiate installed oracle databases on the same machine.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. Thanks for confirming me. I had seen this once upon a time with two MS SQL servers installed on my machine.